# The input and output of the function contain references, which can be mistakenly judged by the compiler's incompetence

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a piece of Rust code.

```
fn f1<'a>(a: &'a String, b: &'a String) -> &'a String {
    a
}

fn f2<'a>(a: &'a mut String, b: &'a mut String) -> &'a mut String {
    b
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = "aaa".to_string();
    let mut b = "bbbbbbb".to_string();

    let c = f1(&a, &b);
    let d = f2(&mut a, &mut b);

    println!("{}", c);
    println!("{}", d);
}
```

The compilation error for the above code is as follows.

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `a` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/bin/main12.rs:16:16
   |
15 |     let c = f1(&a, &b);
   |                -- immutable borrow occurs here
16 |     let d = f2(&mut a, &mut b);
   |                ^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
17 |
18 |     println!("{}", c);
   |                    - immutable borrow later used here
```

What problem does this explain? Can someone explain it?

Comment: `c` is an  immutable reference to `a`, so `a` can not be mutably referenced as long as `c` exists. The compiler is not incompetent, it does exactly what is should. That is, it enforces Rust's ownership rules where you can only have one mutable reference or `n` immutable ones

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not incompetence by the compiler, it's exactly doing what you tell it to:

```rust
fn f1<'a>(a: &'a String, b: &'a String) -> &'a String {
```

tells the compiler that both arguments `a` and `b` are borrowed for as long as you hold on to the returned reference,
the same applies to `f2`.

So later on when you write

```rust
    let c = f1(&a, &b);
```

both `a` and `b` are borrowed for as long as you keep using `c`.
In the very next line you try to borrow `a` and `b` mutable:

```rust
    let d = f2(&mut a, &mut b);
```

but that's not allowed because you use `c` later on in your code.

So in conclusion the borrow checker is exactly doing what it was designed to do, avoid the case where you have a mutable reference and some imutable reference to the same memory location at the same time.

This toy example can easily be changed to compile by rearranging the lines:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a = "aaa".to_string();
    let mut b = "bbbbbbb".to_string();

    let c = f1(&a, &b);
    println!("{}", c);

    let d = f2(&mut a, &mut b);
    println!("{}", d);
}
```

Comment: This sentence you said made me understand: "tells the compiler that both arguments a and b are borrowed for as long as you hold on to the returned reference". Thanks